optimization, geometry, integration, analysis
Given a sphere, a straight tube with circle cross section is bored out through the center. For a separate but same sphere, a straight tube with square cross section is bored out through the center. The circle and square cross sections have the same area. For the bored-out volumes, which one is bigger, the circular tube versus the square tube?
Intuition suggests the circular tube is bigger. By the non-rigorous thoughts about symmetry, likely the biggest volume for all different cross section shapes is circle, or is it? Is there a software site so I can caluculate for different cross section shapes (with the same area), and I don't have to do manual integration? I realize that an analytical argument approach may not be feasible. Just like a fix line length encompass the largest area in the shape of a circle, there is no completely rigorous analysis on it, but everyone believes so.
This is a small part of a bigger research project. Thank you all for any input.
Is it allowed to hire people to solve problems here? From wikipedia: "The one shape that is perfectly convex and symmetrical is the circle, although this, in itself, does not represent a rigorous proof of the isoperimetric theorem (see external links)." If anyone can provide proof, or progress on it, more in the pure math approach, and I hire them. Would anyone be interested? I am happy also to include them as coauthor on the publication, if it works out, of course if they are interested to be a coauthor.

Welcome to MSE. Please use more specific titles.

Just a little remark on the vocabulary "a straight tube with circle cross section" $\to$ "a cylinder" (whose axis passes through the center of the sphere).

(i) Welcome to MSE! <> (ii) Please do not re-ask the same question; instead, please edit the original as requested and wait for the original to be re-opened. (iii) By "Just like a fix line length encompass the largest area in the shape of a circle, there is no completely rigorous analysis on it, but everyone believes so." are you suggesting there is no proof of the isoperimetric inequality...?

thanks for the corrections and closing the other problem.     Thank you also for isoperimetric isoperimetric inequallity.        Some text  copy and pasted here:  Although the circle appears to be an obvious solution to the problem, proving this fact is rather difficult. The first progress toward the solution was made by Swiss geometer Jakob Steiner in 1838, using a geometric method later named Steiner symmetrisation.[3] Steiner showed that if a solution existed, then it must be the circle. Steiner's proof was completed later by several other mathematicians."

Is it allowed to hire people to solve problems here?     From wikipedia: "The one shape that is perfectly convex and symmetrical is the circle, although this, in itself, does not represent a rigorous proof of the isoperimetric theorem (see external links)."    If anyone can provide proof, or progress on it, more in the pure math approach, and I hire them. Would anyone be interested? I am happy also to include them as coauthor on the publication, if it works out, of course if they are interested to be a coauthor.

Somone who solves that or a similar problem can be the single author of a paper. So far I don't see a benefit in being hired by somebody else during that process.

@kurt   It is that significant a problem?   Oh.....

It is my personal opinion. Good luck finding coauthors. Typically each author makes significant contributions. Don't forget that.

Yes, PNAS, as well as quite some other journals, include statements/disclaimers of each authors contributions to the work.
